# Valgrind shows leak even after delete operation

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a very simple program as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        char *s=new char[10];
        cin>>s;
        cout<<s;
        delete[] s;
}
```

I am not able to figure out what can i do for valgrind to not complain about it:

```
==5139== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5139==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==5139==    indirectly lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==5139==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5139==    still reachable: 31,451 bytes in 759 blocks
```

**EDIT 2 : Adding Valgrind Error/Heap summary report:**

```
==42891== LEAK SUMMARY:
==42891==    definitely lost: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==42891==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42891==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42891==    still reachable: 528,598 bytes in 11,121 blocks
==42891==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42891== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==42891==
==42891== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==42891== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
--42890-- REDIR: 0x52ead60 (libc.so.6:__GI_stpcpy) redirected to 0x4c2d8d0 (__GI_stpcpy)
--42890-- REDIR: 0x52e7590 (libc.so.6:__GI_strcpy) redirected to 0x4c2ab90 (__GI_strcpy)
--42890-- REDIR: 0x52e1450 (libc.so.6:realloc) redirected to 0x4c29aae (realloc)
--42890-- REDIR: 0x52eaf20 (libc.so.6:__GI___strcasecmp_l) redirected to 0x4c2b710 (__GI___strcasecmp_l)
test4.cpp: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test4.cpp: line 4: `int main()'
==42890==
==42890== HEAP SUMMARY:
==42890==     in use at exit: 528,567 bytes in 11,123 blocks
==42890==   total heap usage: 11,374 allocs, 251 frees, 570,897 bytes allocated
==42890==
==42890== Searching for pointers to 11,123 not-freed blocks
==42890== Checked 768,632 bytes
==42890==
==42890== LEAK SUMMARY:
==42890==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==42890==    indirectly lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==42890==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42890==    still reachable: 528,511 bytes in 11,121 blocks
==42890==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42890== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==42890==
==42890== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==42890== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

valgrind --version
valgrind-3.11.0

Comment: Does the *real* valgrind report actually call out that specific line (the first line in `main()` ) by line number?

Comment: Compiler? Platform? Valgrind's complete report?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) on linux

Comment: GCC 4.4.6 is over 8 years old. Could you check with some newer version?  Also, what is the version of Valgrind?

Comment: Tried the same on gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)  and valgrind-3.11.0. Got same results.

Comment: Well, now that seems to be the summary report. Is that the full `--leak-check=full` report ? It's suggested in the report you posted, right above the `ERROR SUMMARY` section.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @anurag86 When you respond to someone's comment, you should address him/her by @, the same way I just did in this comment. Otherwise, he/she might not be notified about your response and you risk that he won't return to your question any more.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced with g++ 7.4.0 on Ubuntu (same valgrind).

Comment: I even couldn't reproduce it with GCC 4.8.5 (Valgrind 3.15). Could you show us the exact whole program (at least, headers are missing and `using` directive) and also the input you are passing to `std::cin`?

Comment: im adding the exact full program

Comment: I wouldn't care too much, it might be some problem with outdated versions of involved software (GCC, glib, libstdc++,...). Your code is obviously fine, if you store less than 10 characters into `s`. And, your OS should release all the process allocated pages at its end. Anyway, you should use `std::string` instead in C++.

Comment: compiler flags? valgrind can show false positives with enabled optimization

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Ouch! I was daydreaming. Sorry for that.